# Cookie set in a plugin visible in admin but not on front

Tags: plugins, cookies

I have created a cookie in a plugin with the basic PHP function `setcookie()`.

This cookie is in a function.

I can see the cookie in my browser console in admin but not on front.

I added just after my function :

```
add_action(  'after_setup_theme', 'nameofmyfunctionwherecookieisset', 0  );
```

But I see no changes.

My question is, how can I get my cookie both in admin and the frontend ?

I am in WP 4.8

Comment: Are admin pages secured (https) but front-end pages are insecure (http)? If so, the cookie can't cross that barrier, and you'll need to make the full site either secure or insecure.

Comment: I use https both on front and admin
All my pages are secured

Comment: I've resolved my problem.
I hadn't define the cookie path, so I've written this and it works :
[code]
define('COOKIEPATH', preg_replace('|https?://[^/]+|i', '', get_option('home') . '/' ) );
[/code]

and put COOKIEPATH as an additional argument to my cookie like : ",COOKIEPATH)" at the end of my cookie where it is set.

Now the cookie path is set on "/" on the front.
Perfect
Thanks